# Random number in loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

My function return the same number sequence.
  When i give on input list with first list[0] all 0 and second list[1] all 1, i get on the output list e.g:

```
1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

And all the time generate sequence on the output is the same.

I mean temp[0] and temp[1] have the same sequence

```
public List<float[][][]> rozmnarzanie(List<nur> list,Random dnd)
{
    float[][][] ftemp=net.wagi;
    List<float[][][]> temp = new List<float[][][]>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < net.wagi.Length; a++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < net.wagi[a].Length; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < net.wagi[a][j].Length; k++)
                {
                    if(dnd.Next(0,100)<=50)
                    { 
                        ftemp[a][j][k] = list[0].listawagi[a][j][k];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ftemp[a][j][k] = list[1].listawagi[a][j][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        temp.Add(ftemp);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Do you need really random numbers? If so, check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wb9c8c67(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean temp[0] and temp[1] have the same sequence

Correct. You add the same array twice, `temp[0]` and `temp[1]` are both references to the same location in memory. What you see are the results of the last run. The same result will show up in net.wagi .

Your question isn't about random numbers but about arrays being reference types.

I don't know what `net.wagi` is but the solution could look something like:

```
//float[][][] ftemp=net.wagi;
List<float[][][]> temp = new List<float[][][]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) 
{
   float[][][] ftemp = new float[a][b][c];  // pseudo code

   ... 

   temp.Add(ftemp);
 }
```

You figure out the a, b and c.